# R: garchFit @fitted values more than the observed ones

Tags: r, statistics, modeling

I basically want the estimate of standard deviation values from a Garch(1,1) model. I'm using the garchFit function of the fGarch pachage in R. The data is that of returns and here's the example of the first 20 data- points :

```
0.003700278
0.063133641
0.03467707
-0.002513615
-0.018899622
0.002568493
-0.002134927
-0.023962345
0
-0.008768084
0.00619195
0.029010989
0.010252029
0.002959831
0.016441821
0.036914144
-0.0208
-0.012254902
0.052522746
```

I have a total of 254 data points. However, when I checked for the fitted values and even volatility I got a total of 1974 values. Where could have I gone wrong? I searched but could not find a similar query elsewhere. The data points are stored in GARCHdata and here's the code snippet:

```
GARCHmodel=garchFit(formula= GARCHdata~ garch(1,1),trace=F)
f=GARCHmodel@fitted
length(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the data parameter, the model is fit onto historical Deutschemark/British pound exchange rate data.